# IE and JQuery: .html() strips tags

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have Country, Regions and Cities selects. When a user changes the Country select, it sends an AJAX request and receives data that looks like that:

```
<div class="regionData">
  <option value="1">Region name</option>
  <option value="2">Region name 2</option>
</div>

<div class="cityData">
  <option value="1">City 1</option>
  <option value="2">City 2</option>
</div>
```

Then I update the other 2 selects

```
$("#Estate_region_id").html($(html).filter(".regionData").html());
$("#Estate_city_id").html($(html).filter(".cityData").html());
```

It all works just fine in all the browsers except for IE (what a surprise). In IE .html() acts as though it is .text() and strips all the tags, leaving only text. Can anyone advice on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is invalid. You cannot have `option` tag inside `div`.

Send your response like this.

```
<select class="regionData">
  <option value="1">Region name</option>
  <option value="2">Region name 2</option>
</select>

<select class="cityData">
  <option value="1">City 1</option>
  <option value="2">City 2</option>
</select>
```

Your JavaScript looks good just modify the response html it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

`<option>` is not a valid tag as a child of `<div>`. Therefore IE is (correctly, I believe) stripping it in `innerHTML` (and therefore `.html()`) and pretending you didn't make that mistake.

Instead, use a `<select>` to hold your `<option>` tags.

Comment: You can, however, accept an answer if it was useful to solving your problem ;)